# SLURM power saving features

Tags: electrical-power, resource-management

For those who have used SLURM resource manager, have you used the [power saving features](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/slurm/power_save.html) to lower your cluster's energy usage?

Has anyone found that power saving lowered their electricity bills?
Did the idle-node-shutdown scripts ever cause problems with performance?

I'm trying to get more information to make an informed decision about whether we should try to use it.  So any experience would be helpful.

Thank you